# Deploying postgresql docker with ssl certificate and key with volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssl, permissions

I'm trying to deploy a postgresql container. I'm trying to put ssl certificate and key in the container using volumes, but I can't get the permissions right. The files need to be readable by the container's `postgres` user, but also have limited permissions(`600`).

Is it possible using volumes, or will I have to override the Dockerfile for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is possible to mount the key and certificate into the postgres container, and for postgres to use them from there. But you will have to face the issue with the owner and permissions of the `server.key`.

From the [PostgreSQL Documentation on this subject](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ssl-tcp.html):

> On Unix systems, the permissions on server.key must disallow any
>   access to world or group; achieve this by the command chmod 0600
>   server.key. Alternatively, the file can be owned by root and have
>   group read access (that is, 0640 permissions).

This means that you have to:

1. Set the owner of the `server.key` file to either `root` or `postgres`.
2. Depending on the owner of the server.key file, you will have to set respectively `600` or `640` permissions on it. (**Update:** It is implied here, that the group owner of the file, is a group that contains the `postgres` user, like the default `postgres`group)

If you are working from a Windows host, you will have a hard time with this. Because the permissions on any file in the volume that you map into the container will be `-rwxr-xr-x` (`755`), and the owner will be `root`. And you will not be able to change this as long as the file is mounted from your windows volumes. If you try using `chmod` on the file, it will just fail silently.

If you on the other hand are on a linux host, this can be done with minimum effort. The permissions from the host system will be preserved into the image. And the ownership will too, litterally. By this I mean, that the numerical owner and group owner of the `server.key` will be preserved when they are volume mapped into the container. Between the host and the container, they share the linux ACL, so they are just observing the same properties of the files. (Owner, group owner, permissions). So if your local linux user on the host machine has `UID:GID` `1000:1000`, and you create the `server.key` file, then the `UID:GID` of the file will also be set to `1000:1000`. If you then map the file into the container, and observe it from inside - it will also just see `1000:1000`. This means, that we can control the `UID:GID` from both inside and outside the container, when mapped from a linux host.

**Note.** There does not have to be a user with the `UID` that you assign as owner on a file, it is allowed to set non existent `UID:GID` owners of files.

In the postgres `alpine` derivative image, the `postgres` user/group has `UID:GID` `70:70`. On the `debian` derivative the postgres `UID:GID` is `999:999`. And not supprising, root has `0:0` on both of them.

This means either have to:

1. Change the `UID:GID` of the file `server.key` **after** we start the container, when the volume is already mounted.
2. Change the `UID:GID` of the file `server.key` **before** we start the container

Since setting this after the container starts, would imply tampering with the startup scripting of the postgres image - let's opt to set them before we start the container. In the local filesystem where you are mounting them from.

### **Setting `600` permissions and `postgres` as owner of the `server.key`**

In case you are going with the `alpine` derivative, you need to change the owner/group to `70:70`. If you are using the `debian` derivative, then `999:999`.

There may not be a user on your host with for example `UID`: `70`, but that is not a problem.

**Example:**

```sh
chown 70:70 server.key # 70:70 for alpine, 999:999 for debian
chmod 600 server.key
```

### **Setting `640` permissions and `root` as owner of the `server.key`**

This example is also for the alpine image

**Example:**

```sh
chown 0:70 server.key
chmod 640 server.key
```

At this point you are good to go. You just need to map the key and certificate into the container, and start postgres like always.

### **Solution (linux/unix/macOS)**

I will include a script snippet here, that will do all of this for you for the alpine derivative. This example will set the root owner of the server.key and the postgres group owner.

```sh
# generate the server.key and server.crt
openssl req -new -text -passout pass:abcd -subj /CN=localhost -out server.req
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:abcd -out server.key
openssl req -x509 -in server.req -text -key server.key -out server.crt

# set postgres (alpine) user as owner of the server.key and permissions to 600
chown 0:70 server.key
chmod 640 server.key

# start a postgres docker container, mapping the .key and .crt into the image.
docker run -d --name postgres \ 
  -v "$PWD/server.crt:/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt:ro" \
  -v "$PWD/server.key:/var/lib/postgresql/server.key:ro" \
  postgres:11-alpine \
  -c ssl=on \
  -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt \
  -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.key
```

I hope this clears things up?

Source of the key generating key and certificate is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrw34/c97bb03ea1054afb551886ffc8b63c3b).

### **Building the image yourself (Windows solution)**

I will include a small guide to how you can build an image yourself, so that you can have a postgres database container with ssl. This will work on Windows aswell.

Here's the Dockerfile that will do it for you:

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine

# On Windows root will own the files, and they will have permissions 755
COPY server.key /var/lib/postgresql/server.key
COPY server.crt /var/lib/postgresql/server.crt

# update the privileges on the .key, no need to touch the .crt  
RUN chmod 600 /var/lib/postgresql/server.key
RUN chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/server.key
```

Build the image with:

```sh
docker build -t mypg:01 .
```

And run with:

```sh
docker run -d --name postgres mypg:01 \
  -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt \
  -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.key
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using linux both for local development and server deployment. I'll try going the root route. I don't feel comfortable relying on the current value of uid/gid of the postgres users in the container.

Comment: I can't get it to work using root as owner and 0640 as permissions. The database fails with ` FATAL:  could not load private key file "/etc/postgresql/server.key": Permission denied`.

Comment: Aww... looks like I jumped the gun on the "setting `root` owner of the `server.key`". Apparently, the postgres user has to be in the group that is assigned the group owner of the file. So that `root:root` is not permitted on the file. That means that you have to use user `70` for doing this (for alpine, `999` for debian). I updated the solution in my answer to reflect this. I hope you can accept that as the answer here? Since it still is possible to do this. Best regards.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but I think I'll prefer to use a custom Dockerfile which `COPY --chown` and `RUN chmod 600` certificate files. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer @AndreasLorenzen! I've tried both approaches (`chown 70:70 && chmod 0600` and `chown 0:70 && chmod 640`) and with the first approach I get `could not load private key file "/var/lib/postgresql/server.key": Permission denied` and with the second approach I get `private key file "/var/lib/postgresql/server.key" has group or world access`

Comment: this solution does not seem to work in osx, apparently the file is not mounted with the right owner.

Comment: Any solution for mac os x?

Comment: Well, in this case the "Windows" solution of building the image yourself would work. I will update the answer if you can confirm that it works like that. I added macos because I read that docker would not behave this way when volume mapping files somewhere - but that appears not to be the case. I do not have a Mac to test this on myself though.

Comment: @AndreasLorenzen This answer provides the server cert/key, how to obtain the client cert/key for connecting to postgres using ssl=verify-full?

Answer (score 6):

In my particular case I was interested in enabling SSL while using the standard postgres image via docker-compose. This solution allows `initdb` to run as usual which is useful for setting up the DB and users.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./postgres-certs/:/var/lib/postgresql/certs/
```

`postgres-initdb/config.sql`

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET ssl_cert_file TO '/var/lib/postgresql/certs/server.crt';
ALTER SYSTEM SET ssl_key_file TO '/var/lib/postgresql/certs/server.key';
ALTER SYSTEM SET ssl TO 'ON';
```

This will work for any configuration. For SSL you will also want to generate the certs (taken from [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrw34/c97bb03ea1054afb551886ffc8b63c3b)):

```
set -euo pipefail

mkdir postgres-certs
cd postgres-certs

openssl req -new -text -passout pass:abcd -subj /CN=localhost -out server.req -keyout privkey.pem
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -passin pass:abcd -out server.key
openssl req -x509 -in server.req -text -key server.key -out server.crt
chmod 600 server.key
test $(uname -s) == Linux && chown 999 server.key
```

Comment: This answer provides the server cert/key, how to obtain the client cert/key for connecting to postgres using ssl=verify-full?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there @steve . This was for development purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

#### The correct solution for MacOS

On macOS because of osxfs driver's behaviour, whatever uid/gid is running in the container is also the uid/gid that owns the mounted files (so files owner on the container will not be the same as the host file's owner).

In MacOS when when we change the file's owner in the container, it writes the owner data at `com.docker.owner` extended file attribute(instead of updating the real file's owner).
so we have to set `com.docker.owner` attribute to set the file's owner for containers in docker (just on MacOS).

**Note**: If your Postgres DB's Image is based on alpine, change `0:999:999` to `0:70:70`

```
chmod 600 server.key
xattr -w com.docker.owner 0:999:999 server.key # 0:70:70 for alpine-based image
```