# How to use SSL key and cert files in docker?

Tags: docker, ssl

I have FastAPI app with uvicorn as starter. This app is in docker container and works fin.

Now I want to run uvicorn with SLL so i need PEM- and KEY-files inside of container. On dev machine theese files are `/ssl/localhost.pem` and `/ssl/localhost.key`, On prod server they are `/ssl/certs/prod.pem` and `/ssl/private/prod.key`.

My idea was to define `SSL_KEY` and `SSL_PEM` env vars with system path to that files and use it in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN cp SSL_KEY /ssl.key
...
CMD uvicorn ... --ssl-keyfile=/ssl.key ...
```

But it doesnt work I do not know why.

Do you have any ideas about how to implement this case? Please :-)

Comment: The SSL certs are obviously environment-specific and so I would think you do not 'bake' them into the image, but mount them into the container at run time. In dev mount in the dev keys, in production mount the production keys.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Good idea!  But it means that SSL-files must be in the same paths on dev, prod and on any server I want to use to deploy? Or I can mount homehow like this: $SSL_FILES_PATH:/ssl ?

Comment: Does [Deploying postgresql docker with ssl certificate and key with volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072221/deploying-postgresql-docker-with-ssl-certificate-and-key-with-volumes) have the information you need?  There are some PostgreSQL-specific concepts, but there's also a fairly detailed walkthrough of using `openssl` on the host to generate the TLS certificate and then bind-mounting the parts into the container.

Comment: (There's also a significant security risk to `COPY`ing the private key in the Dockerfile, since it's very easy to extract it from the image.)

Comment: If you mount the certs into the container then you would mount them into the same place each time - wherever your container application expects to find them. Where you get the files to mount - i.e. from a local drive (if using compose) or config-maps (if using K8S or similar) - is up to you.